# Store.Dispatch() Resetting Redux Store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I `dispatch(action())` to trigger an `action` from outside my react component. It is working correctly in that it is triggering my action and updating the new item in my `store`. The problem is that it seems to be completely resetting everything else in my `store`, which to me at least makes it more of a problem than its worth.

Worth noting: I am using `next.js`.

Here is a basic idea of my flow:

I have a utils folder with a service where I am dispatching this action from:

```
import store from './store';
store.dispatch(myAction());
```

I have my actions

```
export const myAction = () => ({
  type: HELP_ME,
  payload: true,
});
```

```
const initialState = {
  reducerVar: fase,
  otherExistingVar: {},
  otherExistingVarTwo: null,
  otherExistingThree:null,
  otherExistingVarFour: false,
};

const myReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case HELP_ME: {
      const reducerVar = action.payload;
    } 
    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
};
export default myReducer;
```

I am not sure if I am misusing `store.dispatch()` because I dont see why anyone would use this technique if it completely wipes out the existing data in the store. Or is there a better way to trigger this simple action from outside my component.

Basically I want to `dispatch` this action without completely wiping out my store just like I would dispatch the action if I were in a component.

Thank You!

Comment: What does your reducer look like? What does store look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should return the state with value in reducer like this.

```
const myReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case HELP_ME: {
      return {...state, reducerVar : action.payload}
    } 
    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is fine. But your reducer must return the whole state with your change done by the action like below.

```
const myReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case HELP_ME:
      const reducerVar = action.payload;
      return {...state, reducerVar }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```